# What is the number of labeled caterpillars?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

A caterpillar is a tree in which all the vertices are within a distance $1$ of a central path. (See the Wikipedia article: Caterpillar tree,  for an example and some equivalent characterizations).

The number of unlabeled caterpillar trees is given by Sloane's OEIS A005418.  For $n\le 6$ all trees are caterpillars so the number of labeled caterpillars with $6$ or fewer nodes is given by  $n^{n-2}$.

I would most appreciate a symbolic derivation of a generating function that counts these trees.